# textarea trailing new lines when selected via keyboard vs mouse

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, textarea

If I initialize a textarea with 3 rows of text and 3 newlines like this

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="50">
A
B
C



</textarea>
```

When you highlight the text with a mouse the clipboard will contain all 3 new lines. 
[image: Mouse Highlighting]

When you highlight the text with `ctrl+a` and copy the clipboard will contain an extra 4th new line. 
[image: Keyboard Highlighting]

This is causing me some problems in a WYSIWYG editor that I'm working on.  How would you make the copy paste behavior act the same no matter if the text was highlighted with a keyboard or a mouse

Comment: That sounds like a browser bug. I'd file a bug report.

Comment: You're mistaken. What you see highlighted is one (perhaps a browser nuisance). What you copy and paste is another thing. Both with mouse selection and Ctrl+A - you always get 4 empty rows, in both cases. I cannot see why such would result in any issue within a WYSIWYG editor since the outputs are equal.

Comment: @Roko, Correct the visual does not match, the browser highlighting is not even consistent between chrome/firefox/edge.  But, when I paste it and look at the ascii characters it is indeed 3 lines vs 4 in all browsers

Comment: @Evan exactly. It's just a *visual* highlighting inconsistency. And if I remember well, it's been ages we have it.

Comment: @Roko the content of my clipboard is indeed different when you ignore the visuals.

Comment: @Evan Oh, really? I tried only to copy/paste into an empty area with line numbers. I always get the 4 empty rows - in both cases. Didn't tried to compare the clipboard data yet. I thought it was the same given the pasted strings... Can you post a proof that the actual string-data differs?

Comment: @Roko Thanks a ton. I am mistaken, and it is indeed a visual bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. But where is problem?
In both cases you have the same content in clipboard.

Open console and try this:

```js
function showCB() {
  let text = window.getSelection();
  text = text.toString();
  console.log(text.length);
}
document.addEventListener('mouseup', showCB);
document.addEventListener('keyup', showCB);
document.addEventListener('selectionchange', showCB);
```

```html
<textarea rows="10" cols="50">
A
B
C



</textarea>
```

Comment: This demo shows text.length to be 9 in both scenarios.  If I then hit `ctrl+c` to copy the data and paste into a text editor, the number of lines do differ

Comment: I have always the same in Chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome, but it turns out you are right.  In my WYSIWYG editor the different highlighting behavior is much more apparent than a standard textarea and that indeed is my problem.  I can fix it by inserting a dummy linefeed that will improve the highlight visuals when using a mouse.  The visuals are still broken when using a keyboard but I can live with that if the clipboard is consistent.  Thanks.